# Picasso using OKHttp possible to cache all requests?

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

Im using Picasso and OkHttp in my project to download images and I have setup a cache for okhttp to cache my images to disk.  However, many of my images do not have proper cache policys set or expiration dates.  Is it possible to have okhttp just cache all requests, and just ignore the cache policy of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push your server's administrators to set proper cache policies; that'll help out all of your apps and also webbrowsers that consume the images.

Forcing responses to be cached isn't something we offer at the moment, but there is a feature request to track it. You might also try `CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE`, which can help for certain cache settings.